# Using sys.stdout.write with pool.map for multiprocessing - sharing sys.stdout

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is probably something very simple I'm missing.

Why can't I use `pool.map(sys.stdout.write, iterable)` ?

I can use `pool.map(len, iterable)` using **the same iterable** but when using `sys.stdout.write` I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

This is the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reut/python/print_mult.py", line 19, in <module>
    pool.map(sys.stdout.write, messages)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

### Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
import sys

# pool of 10 workers
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
messages = ["message #%d\n" % i for i in range(100)]
print messages
pool.map(sys.stdout.write, messages) # doesn't work - error
# print pool.map(len, messages) # works
```

### Edit #1 - ThreadPool works:

When I use `ThreadPool` (from `multiprocessing.pool`) it works, so I suppose it has something to do with not being able to share the `sys.stdout` stream across processes.

### Edit #2 - manual processes works as well:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

# pool of 10 workers
processes = []
for i in range(10):
    processes.append(Process(target=sys.stdout.write, args=("I am process %d" % i, )))

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

So now I'm confused because the difference I know between a regular process and a map process is the point it forks. I'm not sure how it's relevant here. The only thing I can think of is that map stores the `target` internally and is unable to share it with the workers the way the manual constructor of `Process` does.

Comment: I managed to solve it.

Comment: Write up the answer, please, because I'm surprised by this.

Comment: @pcurry I am surprised as well. just need to confirm this is the actual cause. How can I make sure? (added edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real error is hidden. You can only pass a function that is directly referable from a module namespace. However, in some circumstances there are ways to get around this limitation. Unix has a special feature whereby a process can be forked and all its memory duplicated. This is how instance methods can be 'passed' to a child process -- nothing is actually passed. On the Windows platform processes cannot be forked, but must be spawned instead. This means a new interpreter is started. For the interpreter to run the given function it is sent the name of the function to run and the module it is located in. The interpreter imports the module and looks up the function, before finally running the function.

For a process that is part of a pool, the process has already been started and so it cannot benefit from forking to receive a copy of the appropriate function/method to run. Instead it must use the same technique as when a new process is spawned. This is why you can get your second edit to work, but not the pool to work.

The easiest way to get around your problem is to make print a function rather than a statement.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import multiprocessing
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    messages = ["message #%d\n" % i for i in range(5)]
    print(messages) # <- notice the brackets around the arguments to print
    pool.map(print, messages)
```

Failing that you can define a function that will do the printing for you, and use that as the function for map.

```
import multiprocessing 
import sys

def stdout_write(arg):
    sys.stdout.write(arg)

def stdout_print(arg):
    print arg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    messages = ["message #%d\n" % i for i in range(5)]
    print messages
    pool.map(stdout_print, messages)
```

Comment: How does this fit with edit #2? you could do just that (pass instance method... I suppose) to a process. Or is setting it as a target different?

Comment: Given a much more expanded answer on what's really going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I don't think you need `stdout_write` in the second part of your code. I'll take a deeper look into your answer tomorrow. It's the best one so far.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, exactly, but `pool.map()` is requiring the function to return a string.

This simple change to your program runs correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
import sys

def prn(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    return ''

# pool of 10 workers
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
messages = ["message #%d\n" % i for i in range(100)]
print messages
pool.map(prn, messages) # doesn't work - error
# print pool.map(len, messages) # works
```

I checked the documentation and I don't see this requirement so I don't know why it is being enforced.

Comment: Can you tell the implementation difference between `Process` and `Pool` that causes this? (I know they are totally separate where, but even an idea can teach a lot...). I tried going over the source and gave up in the part where the `task_queue.put(...)` is called for now.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with the title "why does pool.map() enforce a requirement that the function return a value?"  Someone probably already knows without even reading the source code.  I don't have time today to dig into the source code to answer this, or I'd take a look... this is interesting.

Comment: I get that a `map()` function expects the function to return a value, but I don't get why the value can't be `None`.  If you just use a simple `map()` (built-in to Python 2.x, import from module in Python 3.x) you definitely can use a function that returns `None`.

Comment: I don't think that list of `None`s is related. you can do: `pool.map(return_none, range(10))` (obviously return_none is a function returning `None` defined before the pool is defined)